# Iteratively filtering arguments matching a predicate at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, c++17

#### Context

Firstly, some context: I'm using an empty `struct` called `nothing` to emulate something similar to [*"regular `void`"*](https://wg21.link/p0146) in order to prettify some interfaces that rely on chaining multiple function objects together.

```
struct nothing { };
```

Example usage:

```
when_all([]{ return 0; }, []{ }, []{ return 'a'; })
    .then([](int, char){ }); // result of lambda in the middle ignored
```

In the above example, what's actually happening is that I'm packaging all the results of the function objects passed to `when_all` in an `std::tuple`, converting `void` to `nothing` *(in this example: `std::tuple<int, nothing, char>`*), then I'm using a helper function called `apply_ignoring_nothing` that invokes a function object by unpacking an `std::tuple`, ignoring the elements that are `nothing`.

```
auto f_then = [](int, char){ };
auto args = std::tuple{0, nothing{}, 'a'};
apply_ignoring_nothing(f_then, args); // compiles
```

`apply_ignoring_nothing` is implemented in terms of `call_ignoring_nothing`.

---

#### Question

I have a function `call_ignoring_nothing` with the following signature:

```
template <typename F, typename... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) call_ignoring_nothing(F&& f, Ts&&... xs);
```

This function will invoke `f` by perfectly-forwarding all `xs...` for which the compile-time `is_nothing_v<T>` returns `false`.

`is_nothing_v` is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_nothing_v = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, nothing>;
```

The way I implemented `call_ignoring_nothing` is *recursively*. The base case only takes `f` and simply invokes it:

```
#define FWD(x) ::std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)

template <typename F>
constexpr decltype(auto) call_ignoring_nothing(F&& f)
{
    return returning_nothing_instead_of_void(FWD(f));
}
```

The recursive case takes `f`, `x`, and `xs...`, and conditionally binds `x` as one of `f`'s arguments if `!is_nothing_v<decltype(f)>` through a lambda. It then recurses over `call_ignoring_nothing` passing the newly-created lambda as `f`:

```
template <typename F, typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) call_ignoring_nothing(F&& f, T&& x, Ts&&... xs)
{
    return call_ignoring_nothing(
        [&](auto&&... ys) -> decltype(auto) {
            if constexpr(is_nothing_v<T>)
            {
                return FWD(f)(FWD(ys)...);
            }
            else
            {
                return FWD(f)(FWD(x), FWD(ys)...);
            }
        },
        FWD(xs)...);
}
```

I would like to implement `call_ignoring_nothing` in an iterative manner, possibly making use of *pack expansion* to filter out the arguments without recursion.

**Is it possible to implement `call_ignoring_nothing` without recursion?** I couldn't think of any technique that allows arguments to be filtered out during pack expansion.

Comment: To reiterate what I proposed on Slack: turn the pack into a tuple. Generate an index sequence for the tuple. Filter the index sequence (possibly even with a type-level filter, by turning the sequence into `integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...`). Pattern match on that. Expand `get<FilteredIs>(tuple)...`.

Comment: Also porting a comment of mine from Slack, as an answer to "isn't this shifting the problem to the concat level inside `filter`" - you can optimize `join` to avoid being always recursive; an example of that can be found in [metal](https://github.com/brunocodutra/metal/blob/master/include/metal/list/join.hpp).

Comment: As Desproges said: "To my own opinion, opinion I oftenly refers to..." I think that the answer could be posted here, by anybody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not so different from the Griwes suggestion but... I suppose you can use `std::apply()`, `std::tuple_cat()`, `std::get()` and tuples that are empty or with value according the value of `is_nothing_v`.

I mean... something like [edit: improved with a suggestion from T.C. and an example from the OP itself (Vittorio Romeo)]

```
template <bool B, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto pick_if (Ts && ... xs)
 {
   if constexpr ( B ) 
      return std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
   else
      return std::tuple{};
 }

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) call_ignoring_nothing (F && f, Ts && ... xs)
 {
   return std::apply(f,
      std::tuple_cat(pick_if<!is_nothing_v<Ts>>(std::forward<Ts>(xs))...)
   );
 }
```

The following is a working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct nothing { };

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_nothing_v = std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, nothing>::value;

template <bool B, typename ... Ts>
constexpr auto pick_if (Ts && ... xs)
 {
   if constexpr ( B )
      return std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
   else
      return std::tuple{};
 }

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) call_ignoring_nothing (F && f, Ts && ... xs)
 {
   return std::apply(f,
      std::tuple_cat(pick_if<!is_nothing_v<Ts>>(std::forward<Ts>(xs))...)
   );
 }

float foo (int a, float b) { return a + b; }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << call_ignoring_nothing(foo, nothing{}, 12, nothing{},
      2.3f, nothing{}); // print 14.3    
 }
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/T4L36cT6sqMKI1Nf)

Comment: Ooooh, this is neat. The one problem I have with this is that it depends on `tuple_cat` not having a QoI bugs in your implementation (i.e. mileage may vary across stdlib implementations).

Comment: @Griwes - ehmmm... sorry but I don't know what "Qol bugs" are; can you suggest me a reference?

Comment: "QoI" is "Quality of Implementation". Presumably a "QoI bug" is a suboptimal implementation strategy. (E.g. if the library's `tuple_cat` is implemented as plain old recursion, then you haven't bought anything perf-wise; you've just shoved your perf bottleneck down into the library code.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone - I see... interesting and... yes: maybe I've only moved the problem; not solved it; thanks. A doubt: working with variadic templates, doesn't imply (down in compiler implementation) the same recursion problem?

Comment: `s/make_tuple/forward_as_tuple/`

Comment: @T.C. - advantages? avoid unnecessary copies?

Comment: This is really cool. Here's a slightly more abstracted version: https://wandbox.org/permlink/T4L36cT6sqMKI1Nf

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - Thanks. En passant, seeing your version, I feel the need of a constexpr ternary operator. Anyway, I like your version; do you permit me to integrate it in my answer?

Comment: @max66: sure thing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take that doesn't depend on `tuple_cat`. First calculate the positions at which a pack of bools is `true` via a "normal" constexpr function template:

```
template<class... Bools>
constexpr int count(Bools... bs) 
{
    return (bool(bs) + ...);
}

template<bool... bs>
constexpr std::array<std::size_t, count(bs...)> indices() 
{
    std::array<std::size_t, count(bs...)> ret = {};
    std::size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    for(bool b : {bs...}) {
        if(b) {
            ret[j] = i;
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then convert the result to a `index_sequence`:

```
template<bool...bs, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto indices_as_sequence_helper(std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
{ 
    return std::index_sequence<indices<bs...>()[Is]...>{}; 
}

template<bool...bs>
constexpr auto indices_as_sequence() 
{ 
    return indices_as_sequence_helper<bs...>(std::make_index_sequence<count(bs...)>()); 
}
```

Then it's a simple matter of `forward_as_tuple` + `get` with the `index_sequence`:

```
template <typename F, typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr decltype(auto) call_some(std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Ts&&... xs)
{
    return std::forward<F>(f)(
               std::get<Is>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...))...);
}

template <typename F, typename... Ts>
constexpr decltype(auto) call_ignoring_nothing(F&& f, Ts&&... xs)
{
    return call_some(indices_as_sequence<!is_nothing_v<Ts>...>(), 
                     std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
}
```

Comment: Neat! I am just realizing that `if constexpr` I normally use within `constexpr` *functions* or `constexpr` *function-templates* is superfluous... Even the other answer falls victim of this :-).